# Javascript: append at the start of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My client side code below fetches some data from the server and then renders the data on to the screen.

What **'append'** does is that it puts the most recent data at the end of the list, whereas I want the latest data to be shown at the top of the list. I am looking for something like **append before or append at the start**.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
        $('#uls').append('<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>');
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="uls"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method 'prepend' that inserts the specified content as the first child like this:

```
<script>
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
        $('#uls').prepend('<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>');
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="uls"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect I'm enjoy that you have solved your problem @mangobug

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)!

Your code would become:

```
<script>
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
        $('#uls').prepend('<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>');
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="uls"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML for this

```
document.getElementById('uls').innerHTML="<li><p>"+data[i].summary+"</p></li>"+document.getElementById('uls').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways `.prepend()` or `.prependTo()`:

1. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
2. http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

take these

```
$('#uls').prepend('<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>');
$('<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>').prependTo('#uls');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery for this:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('uls'); // Get the ul

var li = document.createElement('li'); // Create a <li>
var p = document.createElement('p'); // Create a <p>

li.appendChild(p); // Add the <p> to the <li>
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].summary)); // Add the text to the <p>

ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0]); // Add the <li> to the first position of the <ul>.
```

**[Working Sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/E4Gjm/1/)**

I know it's more code than the jQuery option, but it's also faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use jQuery I suggest to do it in this way:

```
<script>
var i,
    dataMaxIndex,
    ulsContent = "";
dataMaxIndex = data.length - 1;
if (dataMaxIndex >= 0) {
    for (i = dataMaxIndex; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        ulsContent = ulsContent + '<li><p>' + data[i].summary + '</p></li>';
    }
    $(document.getElementById('uls')).prepend(ulsContent);
}
</script>
```

Some code improvements:
- is better to use document.getELementById selector and wrap it as jQuery
- insert all HTML content one time (not at every iteration);

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8RLcx/